# IIS Manager Failed to Connect

Tags: iis, windows-10

Got a new windows 10 machine, turned on IIS and now every time I try to start it I get the following error. Tried restarting the machine, using my credentials,  turning off and on IIS again, using a system restore to before I started, even tried deleting the inetsrv folder nothing seems to work.

[image: IISError]

Comment: It's hosed, reinstall.

Comment: @Will Reinstall windows as a whole?

Comment: I don't think you can uninstall IIS, it's on disk just disabled, IIRC.  So nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.